# Xcode Multiple Animations in UIkit vs. Cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, uikit, core-animation

I'm currently creating a game in Xcode that will include a decent amount of animations. Would it be extremely inefficient for me to do those animations using CoreAnimation, and will there be a memory issue if there are too many pictures?

I'm wondering if I need to switch to Cocos2d so that I can use sprite sheets and other tools. The game has a strong focus on sound effects as well.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If game then not use UIKit.

UIKit isn't exactly fast when it comes to rendering lots of animated images. A game engine is certainly going to be a better choice for almost any game.